# Make another function call from the FETCH method

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I am writing a POST callout from the LWC component and after the callout want to make a toast notification, but getting error in the Javascript file kindly help me out for this.

Code as below :

```
fetch(URL_FORCE_FUNDS , {
                method: "POST",
                headers: headers,
                body: urlencoded
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    //this.dataFromServer = response;
                    console.log('Here is the Data from Server == '+JSON.stringify(response));
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(function (data) {
                    //console.log('data is: ' + JSON.stringify(data))
                    
                    if(data.serviceStatus == 'ERROR') {
                        this.showToast('Error',data.data.errorMessage,'Error');
                        this.closeHandler();
                    }
                });
```

error i am getting as below

```
   lwcForceFundOnTroubleshoot.js:4 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'showToast' of undefined
        at eval (lwcForceFundOnTrouble

shoot.js:4)
```

Note : showToast method i have already defined in the in the Javascript file.

Comment: looks like `this` is not properly bound in the function body, try using arrow functions which have `this` from parent context. `(data) => {...}`

Comment: can you post any example here.. that will be helpfull

Comment: .then((response) => {
                    //this.dataFromServer = response;
                    console.log('Here is the Data from Server == '+JSON.stringify(response));
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    //console.log('data is: ' + JSON.stringify(data))
                    
                    if(data.serviceStatus == 'ERROR') {
                        this.showToast('Error',data.data.errorMessage,'Error');
                        this.closeHandler();
                    }
                });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally recommend using await/async, as it's far easier to read:

```
try {
  const response = await fetch(URL_FORCE_FUNDS, { method: 'POST', headers, body: urlencoded});
  console.log('Here is the Data from Server == '+JSON.stringify(response));
  if(response.serviceStatus == 'ERROR') {
    this.showToast('Error', response.data.errorMessage,'Error');
    this.closeHandler();
  }
} catch(e) {
  // Do something with error here
}
```

Note that the method this is contained in must have the keyword `async`:

```
async myMethod() {
  // ...
```

Answer (score 3):

this looks like is an error on `this` evaluation as @Damecek suggested.

I also suggest using arrow functions for this:

```
fetch(URL_FORCE_FUNDS, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    body: urlencoded
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('Here is the Data from Server == ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    if (data.serviceStatus == 'ERROR') {
      this.showToast('Error', data.data.errorMessage, 'Error');
      this.closeHandler();
    }
  });
```